# Why does decodeURIComponent( ) fail to decode this string "<?php?>" in my program?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a small program to test form validation in JS but I seem to have a problem whenever the string `<?php?>` is entered in the input, nothing appears at all. Here's my code:

```
    <input type="text" name="text" /><button>Add</button>
    <ul>
    </ul>
    <script>
        function insertText(inputField, insertEl) {
            var text = encodeURIComponent(inputField.val());
            insertEl.append("<li>" + decodeURIComponent(text) + "</li>");
        }

        $("button").on("click", function() {insertText($("input"), $("ul"));});
    </script>
```

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('<?php?>')) === '<?php?>'; // true`

Comment: Why do you encode and then immediately decode again? And why are you using URI escaping at all when you actually need HTML escaping?

Comment: I don't know! The main goal here is to make the input field accept everything that you type into and display the text back correctly as inputed. So I'm just trying a bunch of thing @Bergi

Comment: What you are looking for is `insertEl.append($("<li>").text(inputField.val()))` - using the `text` method, not the `html` one.

Comment: Ok it worked now thanks! Buy what are those `<>` in `$("li")` for? @Bergi

Comment: It's an [element constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), not a [dom selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).